# "Collision" of two charged particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, collision

> Two identical charged particles each carrying charge $q=0.1\,\mathrm{mC}$ and of mass $m=10\,\mathrm{mg}$ are projected along two parallel lines separated by a distance $l$, with equal speed $V_0=104\,\mathrm{m/s}$ in opposite directions. In the beginning electrostatic interaction between the charges can be ignored due to a large distance between them. The minimum distance between the particles is found to be $12\,\mathrm{cm}$. What is the value of $l$?

This is what I imagine is going to happen. At one point, the velocity will be purely vertical, then, after some time, both particles will move with a constant direction, and the line joining them will stay the same.

[image]

First, when thinking of the electrical and gravitational potential energy, I didn't know how to setup my integral since both charges are moving towards each other with changing direction.

To go around this, I thought of taking the relative position of $B$ relative to $A$, which gives me a force on it of $F=2F_{A/B}$, thus my work integral is:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{12}\mathrm{F\cdot dl}=\int_{-\infty}^{12}2F_{A/B}\underbrace{dl\cos\theta}_{dr}=\int_{-\infty}^{12}-\frac{2Gm^2}{r^2}dr=-2\times\frac{Gm^2}{12}$$
This makes me inclined to say that the work of one particle over another is half of what I have written above, but it is kind of not making sense to me as both particles are moving to each other by the same amount in a very short time $dt$, or the decrement in the distance between the charges is double, i.e $2\times dr$.

> 1) Is the above calculation of work for both particles separately? Or is it double just because I have considered the relative acceleration which happens to be of the same magnitude? If not, what about my point on the double decrement just above then?
>
> 2) If my point about the double decrement holds, what if the particles are travelling towards each other but with different velocities? Would the decrement be $dr=(v+u)dt$ where those velocities are in the direction of the distance between the particles?

Back to my problem again, using the work energy theorem, after having found the electric potential energy, I get:
$$\begin{align}
v_f=\sqrt{\frac{kq^2-Gm^2}{3m}+v_i^2}
&\Leftrightarrow 2v_{B_f}=2v_{A_f}=\sqrt{\frac{kq^2-Gm^2}{3m}+4v_0^2}\\&
\Leftrightarrow v_{B_f}=v_{A_f}=\sqrt{\frac{kq^2-Gm^2}{12m}+v_0^2}
\end{align}$$
After this, I don't see how I can relate $l$ to my variables. The total angular momentum of the system is $\vec L=2\vec r_B\times\vec p_B=2\vec r_A\times\vec p_A$, whose magnitude happens to be $mv_Bl=mv_Al$ at the beginning, but which isn't conserved. Even if it was conserved, I have an angle between the force and position vector that it seems that I can't find.

Conservation of momentum is useless since the total momentum is always zero.

Any hints please?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107710/discussion-on-question-by-luyw-collision-of-two-charged-particles).

Comment: @tpg2114  Chat is no good for this discussion: it doesn't handle the latex – unless there's some trick that you can reveal.

Comment: @PhilipWood https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/se-chat-mathjax/jkohnpfocfllikbgkfdcghgjgejcfhjb